# Does Galaxy Tab 10.1 USB adapter allow an external web camera?

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, usb-host-mode, webcam

Does the Galaxy Tab 10.1 USB adapter allow you to plug in an external web camera?

The [Samsung site](http://www.samsung.com/us/tab/index.html) does not appear to say either way (or to even list what you can use with the USB adapter.)

And if it does not, are there any tablets that do?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Galaxy Tab 10.1 USB adapter allow you to plug in an external web camera?

No

> And if it does not, are there any tablets that do?

`Acer Iconia Tab A500`

It all depends on the kernel configuration. You can install custom kernel on any device to make it to allow external camera. It is a lengthy process and involves rooting the phone.